# Use of glm() and graph of regression line

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am new to glms and have picked up the following [text](http://www.planta.cn/forum/files_planta/glm_2002_crc_213.pdf), I am trying to do the exercises and I'm a little stuck on exercises 4.5 question 4.1. The question states that a possible model for the data is a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda_i = i^\theta$ where $i= (1,2,\dots,20)$ is the time index. I want to fit a poisson regression in R using the log link function, such that:
$$
g(\lambda_i)=\log(\lambda_i) = \beta_1 + \beta_2 \log i
$$
In R, I've done the following:

```
y<-c(1,6,16,23,27,39,31,30,43,51,63,70,88,97,91,104,110,113,149,159)
x<-1:20
```

I'm confused about the glm function, I'm pretty sure I should be fitting:

```
n1<-glm( y~log(x), family = poisson (link = log) )
plot(log(x),y)
```

What I'm finding hard to understand is when plotting the regression line, we should be plotting:

$$
\lambda_i =\exp ( \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i)
$$
So we should have:

```
plot(log(x),y)
lines(log(x), exp(n1$fit))
```

which doesn't give a decent looking result, although

```
lines(log(x),n1$fit)
```

[image]

seems to be the right way to go, but doesn't make intuitive sense to me, aren't the fit values giving the linear part of the model??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) clears this up.  About halfway through it describes the object `glm` returns, which has the attribute

```
fitted.values   
  the fitted mean values, obtained by transforming the linear predictors by 
the inverse of the link function.
```

When you do `n1$fit`, R does partial name matching, and gives you `n1$fitted.values`.